# Traveling near the speed of light

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, observers, inertial-frames

If I travel near the speed of light, form a stationary observer perspectives, I will take 1 year plus to travel 1 light year, but in my perspective, would I take less than 1 year to travel to that distance as my time slows down respect to stationary observer's time?

Comment: Yes. That is the concept of time dilation.

Comment: Yes. Please don't ask Yes/No questions, "yes" and "no" are too short to even submit as answers.

Comment: From your perspective the universe would flatten so that distances would appear less.   You wouldn't think you're going faster than the speed of light but you'd see an object 4 light years away appear 3 light years away - for example.

Comment: @Downvoter(s) Why downvote this valid question?

Answer (score 1):

The observer sees you travel from A to B - a distance that, in his frame of reference, is greater than one light year. He sees that you take more than a year. He concludes you are traveling at less than the speed of light.

You, traveling so fast, "see" a much shorter distance (this is the concept of length contraction) $L' = L_0/\gamma$ where $\gamma = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}$ Your "on board" clock is also ticking more slowly: $T' = T_0 \gamma$. So while you think you took less than a year to get there, the speed with which you think you are approaching point B is the same speed that the observer (stationary at B) sees you approaching at. You too don't think you exceeded the speed of light.

If the stationary observer was using *your* clock and *his* length measurement, he might conclude you were traveling faster than the speed of light. But you can't just pick and choose - everything has to be determined in the same frame of reference.